# Nom errors over bytes dont actually implement Error

Tags: rust, error-handling, nom, anyhow

I am building a pretty simple parser over `&[u8]`. Unfortunately, when I try to convert the errors I get into `anyhow` errors, it informs me that the various nom Error types (`nom::error::Error` and `nom::error::VerboseError`) don't implement `Display`, and thus don't actually implement `std::error:Error`. Is there anything I can do to make these errors propagate?

Comment: _"when I try to convert the errors"_ -- what exactly do you mean by that? Code would be helpful here.

Comment: In case anyone else was slightly confused looking at the docs: `Error<I>` [does implement `Display`](https://docs.rs/nom/latest/nom/error/struct.Error.html#impl-Display), but only where `I` also implements `Display` - the issue here is that `&[u8]` doesn't.